# MenuItem.NavigateUrl = Javascript results in opening two window, one null

Tags: javascript, menuitem, popupwindow, window.open

I am using a .NET Menu control that I build dynamically. Some MenuItems are set to:

```
javascript:window.open('{0}{1}','_blank','');
```

because I want these menu items to be opened in a new (popup) window. Example:

```
javascript:window.open('http://google.com','_blank','');
```

Without setting MenuItem.Target, this results in a new window with Google it, and my current window gets set to a content value of "null". The HTML source of the window is "null" - that's it.

If I set MenuItem.Target = "_blank" (it doesn't seem to matter what the value is), my base window is preserved, but I get a third window with contents = "null".

[image: Screen shot of screens that are opened]

I am sure this is pretty simple, but I have tried all the permutations I can come up with.

Comment: I added a screen shot to show results after applying @Gerben's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
javascript:void(window.open('http://google.com','_blank',''));
```